# Conda R unescaped path problem for source installs

Tags: r, windows, conda, install.packages

I have some R source files in `C:\Users\Ludvig\path\to\lib`. Sure this is not the exact path, but you get the idea. Lets call my little package `Lib`.
The source tree for the package looks as one expects it to, with a `NAMESPACE`, a `DESCRIPTION`, a `R` folder and a `man` folder. I want to install this as a package in my R environment.

I have R installed via Miniconda, in the `base` environment. After failing installation via `install.packages(...)` some times, I tried to get closer to the metal.
Consider the following in powershell:

```
PS> cd C:\Users\Ludvig\path\to\lib
PS> R.exe CMD BUILD .
* checking for file './DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'Lib':
* excluding invalid files
Subdirectory 'R' contains invalid file names:
 'Notes.txt'
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'Lib.1.0.tar.gz'
PS> R.exe CMD INSTALL Lib.1.0.tar.gz
* installing *source* package 'Lib' ...
** using staged installation
** R
Error : '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'Lib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Ludvig/Miniconda3/Lib/R/library/Lib'
```

It seems the error stems from an unescaped path, and the fact that I install packages into the miniconda folder under `C:\Users`. I cannot, for the life of me, understand *where* this unescaped path comes from.

I have also tried, in the R terminal

```
> install.packages(
+     "C:/Users/Ludvig/path/to/lib"
+     ,repos = NULL
+     ,type = "source")
* installing *source* package 'Lib' ...
** using staged installation
** R
Error : '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'Lib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Ludvig/Miniconda3/Lib/R/library/Lib'
Warning message:
In install.packages("C:/Users/Ludvig/path/to/lib",  :
  installation of package 'C:/Users/Ludvig/path/to/lib' had non-zero exit status
```

and this is about the same...

What file should I hunt down and fix the escapes in?